# Modifying equations that use INDIRECT() inside ARRAYFORMULA()

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

From what I have read, it appears that INDIRECT() does not function with ARRAYFORMULA(), however have seen some custom workaround solutions for specific situations. Could anyone assist me with modifying the following equations such that I can use ARRAYFORMULA() with them?

Equation 1:

`=IF($I$11<>"", SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'Earnings Pivot Statement'!"&$M$5&"6:"&$M$5&""),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,">="&DATE(A2,1,1),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,"<="&DATE(A2,12,31)),  SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'Earnings Pivot Statement'!"&$P$5&"6:"&$P$5&""),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,">="&DATE(A2,1,1),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,"<="&DATE(A2,12,31)))`

Equation 2:
`=IFERROR(IFNA(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'Earnings Pivot Statement'!"&$M$5&"6:"&$M$5&""),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,">="&DATE(A2,1,1),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,"<="&DATE(A2,12,31))/O2,"-"),"-")`

Equation 3:
`=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'Earnings Pivot Statement'!"&$P$5&"6:"&$P$5&""),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,">="&DATE(A2,1,1),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,"<="&DATE(A2,12,31))`

Appreciate any help I can get with understanding how to modify these!

Edit: Taking Erik's suggestion of not requiring INDIRECT(), I have managed to reference the same set of data using OFFSET() with the following:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($I$11:I11<>"", SUMIFS(OFFSET('Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6, 0, $M$2-1, COUNTA('Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A)+COUNTBLANK('Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A),1),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,">="&DATE(A2:A,1,1),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,"<="&DATE(A2:A,12,31)),  SUMIFS(OFFSET('Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6, 0, $P$2-1, COUNTA('Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A)+COUNTBLANK('Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A),1),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,">="&DATE(A2:A,1,1),'Earnings Pivot Statement'!$A$6:A,"<="&DATE(A2:A,12,31))))`

However, ARRAYFORMULA() is only populating 1 cell currently, not sure why

Comment: Dan, I helped you on a previous post, for which you accepted my answer. And I do help frequently here, as you can verify in my profile. So please take what follows as meant to be helpful (though perhaps not in the way you hope). You've asked 10 questions in less than 3 weeks, most requiring customized, complex solutions. Stack is a free, volunteer-run community designed to offer "small help" to a lot of people; it is not designed to be a place where individuals or businesses can get full-blown project work done at no cost. You're welcome to keep posting, but the well may run dry quickly here.

Comment: That said, you don't need INDIRECT at all. And you don't need row-by-row formulas either. One well-written formula could handle all rows of results for each column in question in your spreadsheet. Perhaps that will give you some direction. But again, these types of custom, complex, time-intensive solutions aren't really what this forum (or any other volunteer run forum) are designed to offer. It's clear you are attempting to build a complete system; as such, I strongly suggest hiring someone (just as anyone in any field must hire someone to do work for them which they cannot do themselves).

Comment: @ErikTyler Hi Erik, thank you for your comment. I have been able to achieve most of my goals myself, although there are indeed times where I simply don't understand something, and I don't think it would make sense to hire someone to help me with 3 lines of code (or at least I imagine that one would hire someone to complete the whole project rather than fix 1 formula, unless such service exists??). Both sheets for which I have asked questions on stack for were personal sheets that I have been using myself for years and have decided to improve on to possibly even share with others in the future.

Comment: @ErikTyler Again, I appreciate any help I can get on Stack, but if a person feels that the help they would be providing would be extremely time consuming and that they should be compensated for such, then they have every right not to answer and could even ask for remuneration.

Comment: @ErikTyler As for your suggestion of not requiring INDIRECT at all, I will explore this to see how I can rework the equation and incorporate the use of ARRAYFORMULA as well, thank you! But to anyone reading this, if at the time I have not answered my own question, please consider me as someone who is still completely stuck on the problem lol.

Comment: Dan, in this case, as you suggest, I did not put in the time to develop the very complex solutions you require. Whether for personal use or business use, large or small, when we can't do something ourselves, we generally must hire someone to do it for us. By analogy, whether you want a giant cake for a corporate event, a wedding cake, a birthday cake for your child or just feel like having a single slice of cake, unless you can make that cake yourself, it is reasonable that you would be paying someone for the cake. And even if you can make it, you'd pay for eggs if you don't have chickens.

Comment: By another analogy, you may pick up an issue of "Psychology Today" in a doctor's office or library and receive some general small help for your specific life issues from reading it. But if you want personal counseling (even just one session), you'd pay for it. Again, you are welcome to continue to post here, and contributors are free to help you. I'm simply cautioning you that asking too much too often tends to leave posters finding that their posts go unanswered altogether. To date, "player0" and I have written all of your formulas. Once player0 decides it's too much... the well is dry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244759/discussion-between-erik-tyler-and-dan).

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Comment: @doubleunary The columns containing equations 1 2 and 3 are B, C and O respectively in the "Statement" sheet. These formulas are currently being dragged down and the goal is to modify them to work with ARRAYFORMULA() instead. Cell B2 contains my first attempt using Erik's suggestion that only populates 1 cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking up data from a pivot table, which seems like an unnecessary step. Try something like this to get the total directly from `'Earnings Input'`:

```
=query( 
  'Earnings Input'!A1:G, 
  "select year(A), sum(G) 
   where B is not null 
   group by year(A) 
   label year(A) 'Year', sum(G) 'Total' ", 
  1 
)

=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      G18:G, 
      query( 
        'Earnings Input'!A1:G, 
        "select year(A), sum(G) 
         where B " & if(len(I11), "= '" & I11 & "' ", "is not null") & "
         group by year(A)", 
        1 
      ), 
      2, false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

These formulas do not require any helper columns. Cell `I11` is a drop-down list that lets you select a name to filter by, or leave empty to show all.

Additional data points can be obtained like this:

```
=arrayformula( if( not(len(G5)) * len(F9:F), "-", iferror( F9:F / E9:E ) ) )

=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    not(len(G5)) * len(F9:F), 
    "-", 
    iferror( 100% - G9:G / isnumber(G9:G) ) 
  ) 
)

=if( 
  len(G5), 
  G5 & " % (" & to_text(round(average(G9:G), 2)) & ")", 
  "No filter" 
)
```

See the new [Solution3](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PJQvhp5Hb78-GwhKQTFUx2-1ypexT9ZD8Tr_rrf7w4Q/edit#gid=1747397152) sheet.

The solution above is still a bit verbose, primarily because of the report format you have chosen. It is usually easier to display the data for all categories at once. To get an idea what that would look like, try this:

```
=query( 
  'Earnings Input'!A1:G, 
  "select year(A), sum(G) 
   where B is not null 
   group by year(A) 
   pivot B 
   label year(A) 'Year', sum(G) 'Total' ", 
  1 
)

=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    isnumber(B3:J15) * isnumber(B3:B15) * isnumber(B3:J3), 
    B3:J15 / B3:B15, 
    B3:J15 
  ) 
)
```

See the new [Solution2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PJQvhp5Hb78-GwhKQTFUx2-1ypexT9ZD8Tr_rrf7w4Q/edit#gid=176176410) sheet.

Comment: However, for the desired result, I have added a few more data points so that the filter dropdown is populated. By playing around with that, you should see in the table what the expected output is. The sheet itself is already functioning how I expect it to, it's just the formulas that can't be used with ARRAYFORMULA() yet.

Comment: I am not very experience with QUERY(), so I am currently exploring some guides to see how I could modify your solution to also account for the filters. I do not understand your last point however of combining the queries into one table, but I'll get to that after understanding QUERY first lol.

Comment: I have come up with the following: ```=query(EAR_INPUT_RNG, "select year(A), sum(G) where G is not null and B contains '" &I11& "' group by year(A)")``` however, I would like it to also show years that have 0 sums; at the moment it does not include that in the result

Comment: I think I figured out the QUERY to replicate columns A and B. I am completely lost trying to do columns C using QUERY since it's a ration of the filtered result over the unfiltered result. You may check the latest link to see it in the same sheet.

Comment: I just added a sheet named solution 3 that shows manually entered results, this is the behavior I am looking for. From your posted solution, it looks like you create the extra total column and then use that to calculate the next column whereas solution 3 does not use this extra column.

Comment: Looking at your solution 2 sheet, I don't think this would be necessary as I already display this in a pivot table in another tab (the totals at least - the percentages display is interesting).

Comment: I see, so it's not possible without that column? Could I hide the column elsewhere rather than inside the table? i.e. could I place those totals around where I had my helper columns previously? Is query able to place this column somewhere else or would I have to create a hidden query elsewhere?

Comment: Use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) to copy data from a helper column, as in `={ J8:J }`. See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PJQvhp5Hb78-GwhKQTFUx2-1ypexT9ZD8Tr_rrf7w4Q/edit#gid=1747397152).

Comment: Just saw it, I think this is what I was looking for. I'll re-work it to my visual needs in my original spreadsheet. I was also able to create running totals and filtered running totals using QUERY() as well using your solutions, thanks!